# Swift Combine Publish Twice

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

```
class ObservableFormViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var isSubmitAllowed: Bool = true
  @Published var username: String = ""
  @Published var password: String = ""
  var somethingElse: Int = 10
}

var form = ObservableFormViewModel()

let formSubscription = form.$isSubmitAllowed.sink { _ in
    print("Form changed: \(form.isSubmitAllowed) \"\(form.username)\" \"\(form.password)\"")
}


form.isSubmitAllowed = false
form.isSubmitAllowed = false
form.isSubmitAllowed = false
```

The output is:

```swift
Form changed: true "" ""
Form changed: true "" ""
Form changed: false "" ""
Form changed: false "" ""
```

My question is:

- why `true` output comes 2 while `false` only 2?
- any better way to remove duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why true output comes 2 while false only 2?

The first output is run when you create `formSubscription`. The next three are triggered by your consecutive `form.isSubmitAllowed = false` statements.

Note that you change `form.isSubmitAllowed`  three times to `false` and in output it occurs only two times:

```
form.isSubmitAllowed = false
form.isSubmitAllowed = false
form.isSubmitAllowed = false

// Form changed: true "" ""
Form changed: true "" ""
Form changed: false "" ""
Form changed: false "" ""
```

This is because you're not printing the changed value but the old one.

Try this instead:

```
let formSubscription = form.$isSubmitAllowed.sink { isSubmitAllowed in
    print("Form changed: \(isSubmitAllowed) \"\(form.username)\" \"\(form.password)\"")
}
```

This prints:

```
// Form changed: true "" ""
Form changed: false "" ""
Form changed: false "" ""
Form changed: false "" ""
```

---

If you want to remove duplicates just use `removeDuplicates`:

```
let formSubscription = form.$isSubmitAllowed.removeDuplicates().sink { value in
    print("Form changed: \(value) \"\(form.username)\" \"\(form.password)\"")
}

form.isSubmitAllowed = false
form.isSubmitAllowed = false
form.isSubmitAllowed = false
```

This prints:

```
Form changed: true "" ""
Form changed: false "" ""
```

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, a published variable is only set internally in the class, i.e.:

```swift
@Published private(set) var publishedVar = false
```

In these cases, it is only a concern of the containing class that the same value is set repeatedly, not of any observers. Observers only want to know when the value changes, and don't want to be notified if the value has not changed, without needing to use `removeDuplicates()` everywhere the property is observed.

For properties like this, we can recreate @Published to remove duplicates for us:

```swift
import Combine

@available(macOS 10.15, iOS 13.0, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
@propertyWrapper public struct PublishedWithoutDuplicates<Value> where Value: Equatable {
    public var wrappedValue: Value {
        willSet {
            if newValue != wrappedValue {
                subject.send(wrappedValue)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private let subject: CurrentValueSubject<Value, Never>
    public let projectedValue: AnyPublisher<Value, Never>

    public init(wrappedValue: Value) {
        self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
        self.subject = CurrentValueSubject(wrappedValue)
        self.projectedValue = self.subject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

This can be used in the same way as `@Published`:

```swift
@PublishedWithoutDuplicates private(set) var publishedVar = false
```

For example, the following code:

```swift
class Test {
    @PublishedWithoutDuplicates var test = false {
        didSet {
            print("didSet \(test)")
        }
    }
}

let t = Test()

let d = t.$test.sink(receiveValue: { print ("Observed \($0)") })

t.test = false
t.test = true
t.test = true
t.test = false
t.test = false
```

gives the output:

```
Observed false
didSet false
Observed true
didSet true
didSet true
Observed false
didSet false
didSet false
```

However, this property wrapper won't work as expected if `Test` conforms to `ObserableObject`, because it doesn't have a reference to the parent object to call `objectWillChange.send()`. To do that, we need to use a private method to get the parent object. Use at your own risk:

```swift
@available(macOS 10.15, iOS 13.0, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
@propertyWrapper public struct PublishedWithoutDuplicates<Value> where Value: Equatable {
    public static subscript<T: Any>(
        _enclosingInstance instance: T,
        wrapped wrappedKeyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<T, Value>,
        storage storageKeyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<T, Self>
    ) -> Value {
        get {
            instance[keyPath: storageKeyPath].wrappedValue
        }
        set {
            guard newValue != instance[keyPath: storageKeyPath].wrappedValue else { return }
            if let observable = instance as? any ObservableObject,
               let publisher = observable.objectWillChange as any Publisher as? ObservableObjectPublisher {
                publisher.send()
            }

            instance[keyPath: storageKeyPath].wrappedValue = newValue
        }
    }
    
    public var wrappedValue: Value {
        willSet {
            if newValue != wrappedValue {
                subject.send(newValue)
            }
        }
    }

    private let subject: CurrentValueSubject<Value, Never>
    public let projectedValue: AnyPublisher<Value, Never>

    public init(wrappedValue: Value) {
        self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
        self.subject = CurrentValueSubject(wrappedValue)
        self.projectedValue = self.subject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

If `Test` is a class, this property wrapper will be updated with the `subscript` static method, otherwise `wrappedValue` will be set directly. We handle both cases here, so the property wrapper will work as expected in structs, classes, and in classes conforming to `ObservableObject` it will also call `objectWillChange.send()`.

```swift
class Test: ObservableObject {
    @PublishedWithoutDuplicates var test = false {
        didSet {
            print("didSet \(test)")
        }
    }
}

var t = Test()

let d = t.$test.sink(receiveValue: { print ("Observed \($0)") })
let d2 = t.objectWillChange.sink(receiveValue: { print ("ObjectWillChange") })

t.test = false
t.test = true
t.test = true
t.test = false
t.test = false
```

```
Observed false
didSet false
ObjectWillChange
Observed true
didSet true
didSet true
ObjectWillChange
Observed false
didSet false
didSet false
```

Modified from [Swift by Sundell](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/accessing-a-swift-property-wrappers-enclosing-instance/)