# Why is didSet called twice on the TextField binding in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, binding, textfield, observableobject, property-observer

I have a very basic view that only shows a `TextField`:

#### View

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Enter a string...", text: $viewModel.string)
    }
    
}
```

The `TextField`'s text is bound to a `string` property on the view model:

#### ViewModel

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var string: String = "" {
        didSet {
            print("didSet string:", string)
        }
    }
    
}
```

I added a `didSet` property observer to perform a custom action whenever the string changes. For this simple example, I only print a string on the console.

#### Observation

When I run this code and enter the string "123" into the text field, this is the output I get:

```
didSet string: 1
didSet string: 1
didSet string: 12
didSet string: 12
didSet string: 123
didSet string: 123
```

#### Question:

Why?
Why is the `didSet` closure called twice for each character I type?
(I would expect it to be called once for each character.)

Is there anything wrong with the code or is this expected behavior somehow?

Comment: I recall in SwiftUI 1 or 2, it was not called at all. If you have sensitive side-effect then try to use property publisher/combine.

Comment: Interesting. What do you mean by using a property publisher? Listening to changes via `$string.sink {...}`?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue and I don't know why this is happening. I know didSet + property wrappers were behaving weird in Swift. Maybe it's a bug?
https://forums.swift.org/t/swift-5-2-struct-property-wrapper-didset-defect/34403/5

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Even with combine .. .$string.sink {...} the value arrives two times.

Comment: I am also having this issue, in my case the textfield also queries my database whenever a new character is typed (to autocomplete the entry) so I'm making twice the necessary calls. Has anybody started a ticket with apple, or made a post in the swift forums concerning this?

Comment: Couple of possible solutions/workarounds here:  https://forums.swift.org/t/why-published-var-didset-is-called-extra-time-when-its-referenced-by-textfield-binding/52940/7

Answer (score 18):

I’m seeing this issue on Xcode 14.2 RC and iOS 16.2 RC, but weirdly what fixes it is adding a `.textFieldStyle(.plain)` or `.textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)`.

I’m really not sure why having no textFieldStyle would affect this, but the binding calls set:{} *twice* when I have no textFieldStyle set, and as soon as I add one of those, it behaves normally and only calls set:{} once at a time.

I hope this helps someone!

Comment: Good catch about .plain "fixing" it...

Comment: Wow. This would be funny if it wasn't so ridiculous.

Comment: Still happens on iOS 16.5

Comment: Removed this surprising behaviour for me too. However changing focus still triggers an update (using Combine). Solved it by using removeDuplicates() on publisher (https://stackoverflow.com/a/63696674/2742007)

Answer (score 0):

There is an operator `.removeDuplicates()` that you can put before the sink and it will publish only unique values.
The problem with `.textFieldStyle` is that you still get extra calls when the textfield loses focus, or at least on macOS.

Answer (score -1):

```
 let binding = Binding<String>(get: {
                textvariable
            }, set: {
                viewModel.setText(query: $0) //add event inside setText
                // do whatever you want here
            })
```